# Error while running django project

Tags: python, django, html

Hello I am doing a django (python) project while running the project I got this error. I dont know what is the error and how it can be solved.

```
C:\Users\SujanRajs\Desktop\YAAS-master\YAAS-master\usatyal\YAAS>python    manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-   py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in     execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named YAAS.settings
```

Comment: What's your project structure?

Comment: @ettanany The project is web application based on django frame work using python. The project is about YaaS where user can bid, make an auction and a admin can band an auction or delete it and some other functions.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you try `from YAAS import settings` or `import YAAS.settings` from a python console?

Comment: @ettanany I did not got what you meant, I am student just learning, Could you please say me in other easy way so that I can understand.

Comment: Your project name is "YAAS" right? you created this project using the command `django-admin startproject YAAS` right? Now run the command `python -c "import YAAS.settings"` and let me know what's the output.

Comment: @ettanany I have made this project using PyCharm IDE diretly, just making new project and by choosing django project. I made this in my schools computer and I just take it in pendrive and copied to my laptop and want to run in PyCharm and it got this problem.

so from your las comment I got this result:

C:\Users\SujanRajs\Desktop\YAAS-master\YAAS-master\usatyal>python -c "import YAAS.settings"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named YAAS.settings

C:\Users\SujanRajs\Desktop\YAAS-master\YAAS-master\usatyal>

Comment: You need to be in YAAS folder before running that command, but seems that you have `settings.py` in `YAAS-master\YAAS-master` right? this is why I asked you to show your project structure.

Comment: @ettanany Its same error as before but you can see the project image:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkvilONoFYDPjjyVrHXMydBlhyPu

Comment: You project structure is not correct, there is no `settings.py` at all in your project, which is not possible if you created the project correctly.

Comment: @ettanany I have another project which seems everything fine but also shows the same result like I asked. I dont know whats the problem. I just created the new project which is blank runs well.

This project shows this error:

C:\Users\SujanRajs\Desktop\project_devkota>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\SujanRajs\Desktop\project_devkota>


https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkvilONoFYDPjjyVrHXMydBlhyPu

Comment: `manage.py` is inside `project_devkota\project_devkota\src`, you need to cd to it first

Comment: @ettanany so I got into src and run it this is what I get

entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django

Comment: Are your sure django is installed? You may also need to take a look at some basic tutorial about creating django projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the settings path correctly in manage.py file. Then your issue will be resolved.

Example Folder Structure:

test project

```
test_project
     __init__.py
     settings.py
     wsgi.py
manage.py
```

Then your settings path will be `test_project.settings`